# OAuth2 difference between callback url and redirect url?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am confused how OAuth2 takes you through an entire flow and redirects you back to the page.

For example, I have an auth endpoint: `/auth/authorize`, callback endpoint `/auth/callback`,
and token endpoint: `/auth/token`

`/auth/authorize` gives back the authorize `code`, redirects to the `/auth/callback?code=mycode`, but how does this smoothly grab the `access_token` and redirect the user to the original page?

Should my `/auth/callback` redirect to my `/auth/token` or something? And then `/auth/token` redirects back to the page?

Answer (score 15):

This might will help you in understanding the flow:
[image]

Reference: https://techannotation.wordpress.com/2015/06/17/spring-oauth2-with-authorization-code/

Comment: A brief textual comment on this difference would be appreciated, according to SO rules.